# Why is my screen choppy when I play HD videos?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xubuntu, video, gpu

I am using Xubuntu 14.04 on an ASUS X55V(i3 CPU and Nvidia 610m GPU). I installed the recommended proprietary driven in the GUI (352.63). I installed Nvidia Settings, too, and it lets me choose if I want to use the integrated gpu or the Nvidia GPU. When I am playing a video on Youtube or in VLC I can see it uses my GPU (but as the picture shows, it does not use video engine... does it have anything to do with it?).
[nvidia settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnahs.png)
I also ticked the ani-aliasing checkboxes, which include the following settings:

- Enable FXAA(ticked)
- Antiostrolpic filtering(override app settings-ticked)
- Texture quality(texture sharpening-ticked)

I installed the Ubuntu restricted extras, well.
 And lastly, I found this:
http://blog.riswan.com/2012/05/how-to-fix-slow-choppy-video-playback.html
I followed all the instructions, with no luck.

```
formatc2013@formatc2013-X55VD:~$ lspci|grep VGA
[00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M \[GeForce 610M\] (rev a1)][1]
```

I would like to know, what is the reason of this screen tearing, and what commands to run in order to fix it!
Many thanks